# ひとつでもいいからだめな例が当てはまらないものさえほとんどない。-- Deciphering -- triple-negative?

Tags: negation, written-language

> 私は仕事柄、米国系企業のプレスリリースやプレゼンテーション資料の翻訳をよくするのだが、 ひとつでもいいからだめな例が当てはまらないものさえほとんどない。

1. When you read this part (above) and nothing else,  does it sound like he (the author 私) is saying that the American presentation slides (プレゼンテーション資料 in English) are good, or bad ?

   > ひとつでもいいからだめな例が当てはまらないものさえほとんどない。
2. I think such awkward sentences usually result from making longer versions of an earlier, simpler sentences.  But I can't think of an earlier, shorter version.  Can anyone?
3. Is this a triple-negative? Is it (awkward but) logically correct / precise ?

『スティーブ・ジョブズ 驚異のプレゼン―人々を惹きつける18の法則』  出版社: 日経BP社 (2010/7/15)

> ■訳者あとがき
>
> 本書の翻訳は物欲との戦いだった。欲しくなるのだ。ｉＰｈｏｎｅが、ｉＰｏｄが、そして、マックブックが。
>
> ジョブズのプレゼンテーションはすごい。　. . . . . . （略） . . . . . .
>
> 「誰も思いつかなかった世界一のアイデアを思いついても、周りを説得できなければ意味がない」 ― 本書冒頭の言葉である。そういうもったいないことが起きる原因として、著者はわかったようなわからないようなバズワードの羅列などを挙げる。個条書きにいたっては諸悪の根源と手厳しい。私は仕事柄、米国系企業のプレスリリースやプレゼンテーション資料の翻訳をよくするのだが、ひとつでもいいからだめな例が当てはまらないものさえほとんどない。その米国人と比較してプレゼンテーションが下手だと言われるのが我々日本人だ。周りを説得できずにいいアイデアを殺すなどというもったいないことが、きっと、毎日、たくさん起きていることだろう。

＞　個条書きにいたっては諸悪の根源　・・・　個条書きが 「だめな例」 なんなら、プレゼン資料はほぼ全滅だわな。ｗ

<sub>「もったいない」が二回も出てきて、両方とも気持ち悪い。　（１～２時間のうちに消えた回答が凄く参考になりました。　熟読しておいて良かった！）</sub>

Comment: 「個条書きが『だめな例』なんなら」より「個条書きが『だめな例』なら」のほうが自然だから、(他のタイポを直すついでに)「なんなら」を「なら」にeditしたんですが・・どうして「なら」を「なんなら」にrollbackしちゃったんですかね（しかも日本語の文章の中に、半角/全角スペースちょこちょこ入ってるし・・）・・そっちの方が自然とか思ってはるんですかね・・まあ人のポストだからど～でもいいけど。。

Comment: 私としては、  　「A,BがダメならCを試すか」　　「A,B,Cの全部がダメなんならお手上げかな」　　　と使い分けたい感じですね。

Comment: どっちでも同じ気がしますが・・。「ダメだ、というのなら」・「ダメだ、となったら」という意味で、文語的な言い方なら「ダメなのなら(ば)・ダメなのであれば」、口語的に言うんだったら「ダメなんだったら」とかにしたほうがいいのでは・・と思いますね・・

Answer (score 1):

It's awkward, ひとつもだめな例が当てはまらないものはほとんどない would be enough. ひとつでもいいからだめな例が当てはまらないものさえほとんどない doesn't rhetorically make sense because it says you can't get even a perfect one when you expect more.

Comment: それだと「ほとんどの資料に、本書に書かれた少なくとも1つのダメな例が当てはまる」という意味に解釈しているのだと思いますが、恐らくこの翻訳者が言いたいのは「ほとんどの資料に、本書に書かれたすべてのダメな例が当てはまっている」だと思います。もちろん、日本人はもっと酷いとも言っていますが。

Comment: 言われてみればそうですね。..